# Is there a way to track progress of a Count query in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, progress, cursors

The question is simple yet I couldn't find anything useful online. Say I'm running a

```
Select count(*) from table_name
```

query, and it takes some time. How can I get information on how many rows have been counted at the moment without sacrificing performance? Like 1, 20, 80... until I get the final result.

Comment: In my opinion, no, you can not

Comment: There is not a way to tell how many rows have been counted so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need exact count, an estimate can be fetched fairly quickly.

```
SELECT reltuples::bigint AS estimate FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 'schema_name.table_name'::regclass;
```

Prior to this query, vacuum analyze will help to make the estimate more accurate

For further information Ref: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Estimate count would be fine, but how would I go about getting that data in a form of a constant stream? Should I run it in a loop and wouldn't it be slow? Also I couldn't manage to put it in a conditional query like 
`SELECT reltuples::bigint AS estimate FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 'schema_name.table_name'::regclass AND id='155' LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10;`